pyttsx3 in MacBook Air M1 Sonoma
import NSSpeechSynthesizer # Used for Python to speak to us
import speech_recognition as sr # Used to translate human voice and pass to text
import webbrowser # Used to open web pages
import pywhatkit # Used to search on YouTube
import yfinance as yf # Used to search information in the stock market
import pyjokes # Used to tell jokes
import wikipedia # Used to search information on Wikipedia
import datetime # Used to get the current date and time

# Listen to our microphone and return the audio as text
def transform_audio_into_text():
    
    # Store the recognizer in a variable
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    
    # Configure the microphone
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        
        # Waiting time
        r.pause_threshold = 0.8 
        
        # Inform that the recording has started
        print("You can start speaking now")
        
        # Store the audio in a variable
        audio = r.listen(source)
        
        try:
            # Search on Google what it has heard
            request = r.recognize_google(audio, language='es-PE')
            
            # Test that it was able to enter and transform
            print("Your request: " + request)
            
            # Return the request
            return request
        
        # In case it does not understand the audio
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            
            # Test that it did not understand the audio
            print("I didn't understand you")
            
            # Return an error message
            return "I'm still waiting..."
        
        # In case it cannot resolve the request
        except sr.RequestError:
            
            # Test that it did not understand the audio
            print("Service is not available")
            
            # Return an error message
            return "I'm still waiting..."
        
        # Unexpected error
        except:
            
            # Test that it did not understand the audio
            print("Something went wrong")
            
            # Return an error message
            return "I'm still waiting..."
            
# Function for the assistant to be heard
def speak(message):
    
    try:
        synthesizer = NSSpeechSynthesizer.alloc().init()
        synthesizer.setVoice_("com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Monica")
        synthesizer.startSpeakingString_(message)
        
        # Wait until it finishes speaking
        while synthesizer.isSpeaking():
            pass
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error using NSSpeechSynthesizer: {e}")
    
    def speak(message):
        try:
            engine = pyttsx3.init(driverName='nsss')
            engine.say(message)
            engine.runAndWait()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error using pyttsx3: {e}")

I have tried using Nsss and pyttsx3 on mac but it says there is an error:

NameError: name 'objc' is not defined. Did you mean: 'object'?

If you look inside a speak function I am using both nsss and pyttsx3, when I use nsss it works fine for me, but not with the other. I don't know what to do, is it supposed to work or change something to be able to run the program using pyttsx3 on mac?
